# How to access QStandardItemModel and it's data using a QModelIndex?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, model, qt5

I have a [clicked()-signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) which knows a selected index which is of the type [QModelIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmodelindex.html).

```
void onListClicked(const QModelIndex & index) { /* ... */ }
```

No I want to access the data of the clicked item. I found out I can access the model using `model()`:

```
void onListClicked(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    QStandardItemModel * model {index.model()};
}
```

But this fails as the model() getter only allows me to return an [QAbstractItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html).

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const QAbstractItemModel*' to 'QStandardItemModel*' [-fpermissive]
```

How to access the [QStandardItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) or even better the selected QStandardItem? My unique identifier is stored in [QStandardItem::data()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#Data).

What I need is something like that:

```
void onListClicked(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    QStandardItemModel * model {index.model()};
    QStandardItem * item {model->itemFromIndex(index)};
    qDebug() << item->data().toString();
}
```

But that does not work. Why is that so difficult. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get the data directly from the model index:

```
void onListClicked(const QModelIndex & index) {
    index.data(Qt::UserRole + 1);
    // ...
}
```

You can use any other role to retrieve different kind of data.

Comment: The role is just doing what I need it to. Thanks again!

Comment: This doesn't show how to get the QStandardItemModel

Comment: @mrg95, you can access model with `QModelIndex::model()` function. However in order to get containing data from an index you don't need the model itself - `QModelIndex::data()` function does the work.

Comment: The model grabbed is const though so you cant, for example, delete rows within it. Only read from it.

Comment: So what? OP asked about **reading** the data and not modifying the model. I don't get what is your point and why did you down-voted this answer.

Comment: why we add +1 to Qt::UserRole ? there isn't another constant to use instead of summing UserRole with one ?

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it:

```
QStandardItemModel *model { static_cast<QStandardItemModel *>(model()); }
```

Comment: Not working. `error: static_cast from 'const QAbstractItemModel *' to 'QStandardItemModel *' casts away qualifiers`

Comment: Just add a `const` in the cast, then. Didn't realize that `model()` returned a pointer to const.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, as I need to retrieve my special model:

```
auto myModel=const_cast<MySpecialModel*>(dynamic_cast<const MySpecialModel*>(modelIndex.model()));
```

This was a perfectly working solution for me.

But, there seems to be an important issue doing so:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html

It says there:

***A const pointer to the model is returned because calls to non-const functions of the model might invalidate the model index and possibly crash your application.***

Unfortunately, the docs didn't say, why there might be a possible crash and what one shouldn't do.